# when reading sectors from hdd, my code gets stuck in endless loop

Tags: assembly

I found a sample code on the Internet to read sectors from hdd in protected mode. However, `still_going` section of that code causes an endless loop. I don't understand what is wrong with this code. `ch` register contains sector count and `ebx` register contains the starting offset to put the read data. I need help. Thank you.

```
disk_load:
mov     dx,1f6h         ;Drive and head port
mov     al,0a0h         ;Drive 0, head 0
out     dx,al

mov     dx,1f2h         ;Sector count port
mov     al, ch          ;Read ch sectors
out     dx, al

mov     dx,1f3h         ;Sector number port
mov     al,2            ;Start reading from sector two
out     dx,al

mov     dx,1f4h         ;Cylinder low port
mov     al,0            ;Cylinder 0
out     dx,al

mov     dx,1f5h         ;Cylinder high port
mov     al,0            ;The rest of the cylinder 0
out     dx,al

mov     dx,1f7h         ;Command port
mov     al,20h          ;Read with retry.
out     dx,al
still_going:
in      al,dx
test    al,8            ;This means the sector buffer requires servicing.
jz      still_going     ;Don't continue until the sector buffer is ready.

mov     cx, 256        ;One sector /2
mov     edi, ebx
mov     dx, 1f0h         ;Data port - data comes in and out of here.
rep     insw
ret
```

Comment: As a guess, you might try `jnz` instead of `jz`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to check the check the BSY (bit 7) and ERR (bit 0) flags of the status register (`01F7h`). First wait for the BSY flag to clear, then check to see whether the DRQ (bit 3) or ERR flag was set.  If DRQ flag is set then you can read the data. If ERR is set you should read the error register (`01F1h`) to find out what the error is.

You should also implement some sort of timeout so you can better recover from other errors or unexpected device behaviour. Also while your code requests a variable number of sectors (as indicated by the `CH` register), you only read in 512 bytes regardless.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Should I check those flags with `test` instruction like `test al, 10000000b` (checking the BSY). I am new to low level sector reading. Is there any code example available?

Comment: Yah, a `test` instruction would be a reasonable way to check. Sorry I can't recommend example source code.

Comment: I have tried everything but this code doesn't work for me. What about switching to real mode and using int 13h when reading sectors then switching back to protected mode again? Would that approach have any disadvantages?

Comment: It's certainly possible to switch back to real mode. Windows 95 would do that if there wasn't a protected mode drive available. (Actually it used virtual 8086 mode, but it's much the same thing.) You'll have to make sure that you've left the conventional memory areas the BIOS uses intact. The big disadvantage is that'll be much slower this way, and it might not be easier to get right.